# LIDAR data for Israel

Tags: data-request, geospatial, images, oceanographic

Are there any public sources for LIDAR data for the country of Israel? Searching online has not lead me to find any sources out there.

Answer (score 2):

The "[Israel's Mediterranean Sharon sea cliff, 2006" dataset](http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/datasetMetadata?otCollectionID=OT.102016.2039.1) is available via OpenTopography. It covers "a 30-km-stretch of coastal cliffs in central Israel that lie between the cities of Herzlia in the south and Olga in the north". I know data have also been collected over the Dead Sea rift but they are not yet publicly available.